# How to modify use cookie to access protected page

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, cookies

I have the cookies of a phpsessid and I would like to use them to access a page. But using `document.cookie = 'blah blah'` doesn't work, I still get the dialog and an other PHPSESSID is prepended.
Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Sounds like session hijacking! ....

Comment: @Novice Yeah maybe, or just wanting to resume a session in another navigator 

Comment: Server might be sending some other cookie too to track you.If they are http only then you will not see them using `document.cookie` but only through devtools. In theory if you can achieve this goal if you could correctly copy all the cookies of a logged in user  including session cookie(PHPSESSID) into you un-logedin browser.Server guys will usually employ a IP based fraud detecter so even if you copy everything correctly but loged in user was from Texas and you are in Ohio then it might not work.Also browser finger-printing puts another hurdle.